# How to send e-mail using infopath forms in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, infopath-2007

I'm very new to infopath & sharepoint. I have created a form in infopath & successfully deployed to sharepoint. ( i referred this link -http://www.marclenferna.com/blog/archive/2009/01/18/how-to.-publish-your-infopath-form-to-sharepoint--a.aspx).
In my form i have an e-mail text box & i need to send a notification kind of e-mail to the user, after submitting the form.
Please let me know the steps or methods to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set up a workflow in SharePoint so that when a new form gets submit an email gets sent.  You can use SharePoint Designer to create the workflow.  Promote your email address field from Infopath to a column in your document library, and use that in your workflow.